# How to insert custom facts to PuppetDB

Tags: puppet

I'm using the last version of puppet server, and I'm connecting the puppet server to **Puppetdb** to store catalogs and facts in puppet db.

after hours of installing and configuration. node's facts are now stored in puppet db.

Now after installing PuppetDB I would like to insert custom facts to Puppetdb. here is the following scenario I made :

- I added a new node to the puppet server
- I used the puppetdb api to add a custom fact :

> POST http://puppetserver:8080/pdb/cmd/v1

```
{
  "command":"replace facts",
  "version": 5,
  "payload": {
    "certname":"newnodehostname",
    "environment":"production",
    "producer_timestamp":"TIMESTAMP",
    "producer":"newnodehostname",
    "values":{
      "newfact":"newfactvalue"
    }
  }
}
```

Then when I launch the puppet agent my new fact is deleted, and new facts are saved.

So my question is: why my new fact is deleted when I run the puppet agent on the node ?

Comment: https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/custom_facts.html

Answer (score 0):

PuppetDB stores [the most recent set of facts for every node](https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/5.2/index.html#what-data).

So when during puppet run the agent uploads the new set of facts, it overwrites the ones you sent with your one-time PuppetDB API call.

You should consider adding your custom fact as a, well, [custom fact](https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.11/custom_facts.html) so that the fact will be set during each puppet run.

Arguably the simplest way to do that for a single node is:

1. Create `my_fact.sh` file in `/etc/facter/facts.d/` dir on your node (`newnodehostname`)
2. Make it executable
3. Put something like this into this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^^^^^^^^^ - note that shebang is REQUIRED for custom fact scripts

# all output in KEY=VALUE format will be treated as custom fact names and their values
echo "newfact=newfactvalue"
```

For more information, including information how to add custom facts with puppet manifests on your nodes please refer to the full custom facts [documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.11/custom_facts.html).